# Multiple threads extracting text from iText pdf

Tags: java, multithreading, pdf, itext, text-extraction

I have been trying to speed up extracting text from PDF files. I have tried SnowTide's `PDFTextStream`. It was slower than iText on my computer.

My latest attempt is to use multiple threads.

I initialize the `PdfReader` with a byte array instead of the file name.
  This is so that I can avoid IO latency by pulling all of it into memory. From what I can tell iText gets data from the file as it needs it. With the byte array it shouldn't have that problem.

I use the threads to extract multiple ranges of pages.

However, this has made it a lot slower. Using one thread versus five is faster. I don't know why it is. From what I can tell, the bottlneck is extracting the page itself `PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(mReader, i)`. I timed the for loop which concatenates the thread's text and that doesn't hurt the overall time.

My question is, why is it slower and how can I make it faster?

Is accessing the same `PdfReader` creating the bottleneck?
Should I initialize multiple `PdfReader`'s with the same byte array?
Am I wrong about any of my research?
If anyone has suggestions about entirely new open source PDF extractors or other suggestions, that would be great!

```
import java.io.*;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor; 
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;

public class PDFParser
{
    private PdfReader mReader;
    private int numPages;
    private String bodyText;

    public PDFParser(String pdf)
    throws IOException
    {
    /*
      scrapped this
               mReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
      and replaced with the following. 
      From what I can tell Pdfreader with the above constructor 
      probably uses a stream to get the pages one at a time.
      I want to load it all into memory to increase the speed.
    */

        final FileChannel channel = new FileInputStream(pdf).getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(byteArray);
        channel.close();

        mReader = new PdfReader(byteArray);

        numPages = mReader.getNumberOfPages();
        bodyText = "";
    }

    public String parse()
    {
        int numThreads = 5;
        int offset = (numPages / numThreads) - 1;
        int currentFirstPage = 1;
        ParserThread[] threads = new ParserThread[numThreads];
        int forEnd = numThreads - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < forEnd; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new ParserThread(mReader, currentFirstPage, currentFirstPage + offset);
            threads[i].start();
            currentFirstPage += offset + 1;
        }
        threads[forEnd] = new ParserThread(mReader, currentFirstPage, numPages);
        threads[forEnd].start();

        try
        {
            long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            threads[i].join();
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - before);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){ie.printStackTrace();}
        mReader.close(); 

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads;i++)
        {
            sb.append(threads[i].getText());
        }

        bodyText = sb.toString();
        if (bodyText != "")
            return bodyText;
        else
            return "error";
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
        {
            String text = new PDFParser(args[i]).parse();
            //      System.out.println(text);
        }
    }

}

class ParserThread extends Thread
{
    private PdfReader mReader;
    private int mFirstPage;
    private int mLastPage;
    private String text;

    ParserThread(PdfReader reader, int firstPage, int lastPage)
    {
        mReader = reader;
        mFirstPage = firstPage;
        mLastPage = lastPage;
        text = "";
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            for (int i = mFirstPage; i <= mLastPage; i++)
            sb.append(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(mReader, i));
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        text = sb.toString();
   }

   public String getText()
   {
       return text;
   }
}
```

Comment: How big are the documents you use? I applied your threaded parser to the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) multiple times both with `numThreads = 5` and `numThreads = 1.` The results: With 1 thread: 3114; With 5 threads: 940; With 1 thread: 1877; With 5 threads: 817; With 1 thread: 1894; With 5 threads: 800; With 1 thread: 1845; With 5 threads: 850.

Comment: I have been testing it on a document with 339 pages 1.7MB. I just have tested it on more documents, and on another computer. five threads are still slower, on the other computer it is going a lot slower (10824 vs 5587). What version of iText are you using?

Comment: Trunk, i.e. 5.4.4-SNAPSHOT currently. Please also test with the PDF specification or give a link to your document; then results become comparable.

Comment: Ok, I tested it on the PDF specification. I downloaded the latest version that is on their website which is 5.4.3. With five trials each I got - Five Threads: 7629, 6905, 7156, 6929, and 7396. One Thread: 6827, 6653, 7194, 6586, and 6602.

Comment: What kind of processor do you have? Depending on it multitaskingmax or may not help.

Comment: Sorry, it has been a long time. I don't know why that didn't cross my mind. I was using it on a server that only had one processor.